# В чем смысл перебора с возвратом?

Tags: c, алгоритм, рекурсия

При чем тут рекурсия , в чем заключается её роль в переборе с возвратом ? Она и заставляет алгоритм возвращаться  на предыдущие шаги ? 
И что такое перебор с возвратом ?

Comment: Перебор с возвратом - совсем не обязательно реализуется с использованием рекурсии...

Comment: @Harry,а если с рекурсией , как ,например,в задаче о 8 ферзях ?

Comment: Я всего лишь хочу сказать, что рекурсия не обязательна. Если ею удобно воспользоваться - нет проблем, но говорить о какой-то ее особой роли?..

Comment: В книге "Алгоритмы и структуры данных" Вирта  алгоритм с решением записан с рекурсией , но я не могу понять, почему ей было отведена такая роль, возможно, в этом инструменте и заключается смысл алгоритма , то есть возврат на предыдущие шаги , и с этим у меня не получается разобраться

Comment: Рекурсия - она по определению с возвратом... А её роль... ну её МОЖНО использовать.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Алгоритмическая рекурсия - это по определению алгоритм, построенный по стратегии [Разделяй-и-Властвуй](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) (Divide-and-Conquer), в котором для хранения подзадач использована [LIFO структура данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA), т.е., попросту выражаясь, *стек*.

У таких алгоритмов натуральным образом есть *прямой ход*, когда задача разбивается на более мелкие подзадачи, которые заносятся в стек. Затем подзадачи извлекаются из стека по одной и решаются по такому же принципу, т.е. разбиваются на еще более мелкие подзадачи. Разбиение продолжается до тех пор, пока подзадача не станет *тривиально решаемой*.

А также у рекурсивных алгоритмов есть *обратный ход*, когда все более мелкие подзадачи уже решены и их решения теперь можно *объединить* в решение более крупной задачи.

Наличие *обратного хода* (backtracking) - отличительная черта именно рекурсивных алгоритмов. Т.е. в рекурсии всегда есть обратный ход. Вот, собственно, "при чем здесь рекурсия".

Не всем рекурсивным алгоритмам существенно *нужен* этот обратный ход - некоторым алгоритмам просто ничего не нужно делать на обратном ходе. Но сам процесс обратного хода в рекурсивном алгоритме всегда присутствует, путь даже и незримо.

Поэтому если вы рассматриваете какой-то рекурсивный алгоритм (перебора или чего-либо еще), то там всегда обязательно будет и "возврат" (т.е. обратный ход). А уж как он используется в вашем алгоритме и используется ли вообще - зависит от алгоритма.

---

В рекурсивном алгоритме расстановки `N` ферзей на шахматной доске подзадачей является задача расстановки оставшихся `m` ферзей (`m <= N`), когда первые `N - m` ферзей уже как-то расставлены. Обратный ход в этом алгоритме используется тогда, когда мы вдруг выяснили, что подзадача *не имеет решения* - мы возвращаем этот результат на предыдущий уровень рекурсии в процессе обратного хода и тем самым говорим ему, что надо попробовать какой-то другой вариант расстановки `N - m` первых ферзей. А также, если вам поручено найти *все* возможные расстановки (а не какую-то одну), обратный ход рекурсии будет использоваться для тех же целей независимо от того, успешно или нет решена подзадача.

Comment: Какой обратный ход в хвостовой рекурсии, если компилятор вывернул её в цикл?

Comment: @0andriy: "Компилятор"? Какой еще "компилятор"? Я веду речь об *алгоритмической рекурсии*, т.е. о структуре *алгоритма*. Ни слова ни о каких конкретных языках программирования или компиляторах в вышесказанном нет. Рекурсивный алгоритм - он всегда рекурсивный. А уж как вы его будете реализовывать и что там у вас потом "компилятор вывернет" к вопросу никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Хвостовая рекурсия — тоже алгоритм, цель которого избежать рекурсию.

Answer (score 4):

Смысл перебора с возвратом - мы начинаем перебирать разные варианты, но сразу отсекаем варианты пачками, если видим, что изначально они не в состоянии привести к правильному результату. Рекурсия при этом может быть использована - если она упрощает решение задачи, но совсем не обязательна.

Ну вот представьте... ну, скажем, не ферзей, а обход доски конем. Начинаем с какой-то клетки. Записываем все возможные варианты ходов. Делаем первый же, опять записываем возможные вторые ходы... Уже натыкаемся на то, что не все возможны - например, ход назад невозможен, эта клетка уже занята. Чем дальше вглубь будем заходить - тем меньше возможных ходов будет. В какой-то момент просто не удастся пойти никуда.

И вот тут действует возврат! Мы просто возвращаемся на ход назад, и пробуем дальше. Опять, пока не окажется, что дальше некуда - опять возврат.

А так как эти возвраты будут происходить гораздо раньше достижения N<sup>2</sup> хода - то мы отбрасываем сразу многие и многие варианты.

Таким образом, перебор оказывается далеко не полным и может быть выполнен за небольшое время.

Рекурсия облегчает жизнь - мы можем искать очередные варианты ходов рекурсивно, храня их в стеке автоматически при вызове, но можем вполне помещать в свой собственный стек, например...

Наверное, следовало бы привести пример, но это приведет только к долгому описанию подробностей реализации, возможно, для понимания просто лишних. Но если вы настаиваете...