# Запись числа как суммы треугольных чисел

Tags: алгоритм, математика, динамическое-программирование

Попалась новогодняя задачка - записать число 2018 как сумму разных [треугольных чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE).

Вообще-то, не так чтобы сложно, на бумажке решить можно, но там было приведено общее количество таких записей. Как их посчитали? Таких чисел, меньших 2018 - аж 63, так что перебором - вряд ли.

Мне все покоя не дает не дающееся мне динамическое программирование - им тут можно как-то добраться до ответа?

Если кто сомневается - это задание не учебное :)

Comment: Первое что пришло в голову - строить бинарное дерево.

Comment: Обычная задача о неограниченном рюкзаке. Да ещё и с равной стоимостью. На что тут динамическое программирование? вполне достаточно вульгарного метода ветвей и границ. За вполне вменяемое время решается рекурсивной функцией (правда, глубина рекурсии в 2018 не вдохновляет)...

Comment: @Akina У меня вышла рекурсия глубиной не более 64, правда, раздваивающаяся...

Comment: *У меня вышла рекурсия глубиной не более 64* Пардон, я пропустил, что искать надо *сумму **разных** треугольных чисел*

Comment: @Akina Гляньте мой дополненный ответ - думаю, в этом случае никакая рекурсия бы не выдержала :) И таки ТС был прав в плане применения ДП...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй раз наталкиваюсь на задачу, которую можно решить длинно, а можно очень быстро... :) Первый ответ опять не убираю, но настоящее решение - в части **Update**...

Тут недавно спрашивали о [переборе с возвратом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767038/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC) :) - это почти оно самое. Кстати, с применением рекурсии для упрощения.

Итак, решение может включать некоторое треугольное число, может не включать. В любом случае задача сводится к поиску решений для либо того же числа (если не включаем) или меньшего на включенное треугольное число - но уже для меньшего множества треугольных чисел. Получается рекурсия не глубже 64, но на каждом уровне - ветвящаяся. Но так как отбрасывается очень много вариантов - то посчитать реально, у меня на машине - за примерно 9.5 секунд.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> tri;      // Запас треугольных чисел :)
long long total = 0;  // Количество решений

vector<int> solution; // Вектор для решения

// Рекурсивный вызов, изначально - доступны все числа (k)
void getThree(int n, int k = tri.size()-1)
{
    if (n==0)  // Ура, найден!
    {
        ++total;
        // Если захотим вывести - раскомментировать
        // for(auto i: solution) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (n < 0 || k < 0) return;    // Тупик - решение не получилось

    // Ветвь с использованием k-го числа
    solution.push_back(tri[k]);
    getThree(n-tri[k],k-1);
    solution.pop_back();

    // Ветвь без него
    getThree(n,k-1);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // Заполняем массив треугольными числами
    for(int i = 1; i <= 64; ++i) tri.push_back(i*(i-1)/2);

    // Приступаем...
    getThree(2018);
    cout << total << endl;
}
```

На ideone [времени не хватает](https://ideone.com/E0HZiP) :(

У меня выходит 2693210 вариантов (P.S. так что с `long long` я явно пожадничал :))

Может, есть какой алгоритм побыстрее - не знаю, но готов поверить :)

**Update**

Есть и побыстрее, и именно динамическим программированием!

Итак, просто создаем массив

```
long long res[2019][65];
```

в котором изначально все элементы - -1, и который указывает количество способов записать число `n` треугольными числами на выше `k`-го в ячейке `res[n][k]`.

наша основная формула остается та же, что и ранее -

```
getThree(n-tri[k],k-1) + getThree(n,k-1)
```

только теперь мы используем memoization и записываем ответы в массив.

Т.е. функция приобретает вид

```
long long getThree(int n, int k = tri.size()-1)
{
    if (n < 0 || k < 0) return 0;    // Не вышло
    if (k == 0)                      // Годится как вариант n==1, так и n==0
    {
        if (n == tri[k]) res[n][k] = 1;
        if (n == 0) res[n][k] = 1;
    }
    else if (n == 0) res[n][k] = 1;   

    if (res[n][k] == -1)    // Если мы еще не рассчитывали это значение - 
    {                       // считаем и сохраняем
        res[n][k] = getThree(n-tri[k],k-1) + getThree(n,k-1);
    }
    return res[n][k];
}
```

[Такой код](https://ideone.com/i5CmFX) позволяет мгновенно получить тот же результат - 2693210.

А вот почему я оставил `long long`: если позволить выбирать значения повторно (ну, типа, 9 можно писать и как 6+3, и как 3+3+3), то чтобы получить это количество, достаточно просто заменить

```
getThree(n-tri[k],k-1)
```

на

```
getThree(n-tri[k],k)
```

(т.е. можно использовать то же число повторно). [Результат получается тоже весьма быстро](https://ideone.com/b6IYzh), только он куда побольше, так что перебором с отсечением уже не обойтись: 32090936486947985

А неплохая задачка :)

Comment: Я знал, я знал! :) Спасибо!